# RadioButton jQuery Mobile formatting issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get a radio button list using an AJAX call. However there are problems in the formatting with my list looking like this.

```
(Radio-button)
Text
```

This is my code:

```
$.get(
    "schedulePortal.php?uid="+uid,
    function( data ){
    $('#semList').html( data )
    .controlgroup( 'refresh' );
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="semList" style="margin-left : 30px;">
        <!-- FROM PHP Response -->
        <input type="radio" class="radio-choice" value="'.$row['Enrolment_session'].'_'.$row['Semester_session'].'" />';
        <label>'.$row['Enrolment_session'].' '.$row['Semester_session'].'</label>;
        <!-- END OF PHP Response -->
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you vote this down

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

The label needs a for attribute and the input needs a unique id such that the for and id have the same value. e,g:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="rad0" class="radio-choice">
<label for="rad0">The Radio Label</label>
```

After adding the dynamic radio buttons, instead of refreshing the controlgroup, initialize the checkboxradio widget:

```
$('#semList').html( data );
$('#semList input[type="radio"]').checkboxradio();
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/UGe5W/)**